# Making use of newOutputStream method to define file location

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, opencsv

I've the following code working fine in terms of CSV file creation (only showing relevant code below):

```
rsCompany = pstmtCompany.executeQuery();
Path dir = Paths.get("/srv/custom_users", userName);
Files.createDirectories(dir);

Path filecompany = dir.resolve("company_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
    try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(filecompany))) {
            writer.writeAll(rsCompany, true);
  }
```

Now, let's say I want to create a zip file for the same, how should I make use of the `dir` variable (that I used in the above scenario) in this line `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your_files.zip");` of code below?

I mean, I have to define the following things:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("/srv/custom_users", userName);
Files.createDirectories(dir);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your_files.zip");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos); 


ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getFileName().toString());
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
       writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
       writer.flush();
       zos.closeEntry();
}
zos.close();
```

If I go ahead and use `newOutputstream` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) of `Files` class, it may looks like the following :

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(dir));
```

Is it a correct way to go about it?

I'm wondering, where should I place the name of the zip file , I mean, `your_files.zip` that I defined in my previous line of code `FileOutputStream("your_files.zip");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need a FileOutputStream.  At all.

You only need an OutputStream, and that is what Files.newOutputStream returns:

```
OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(dir.resolve("your_files.zip"));
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked !! Thanks very much ! By the way, what was the reason of not using `FileOutputstream` and just using `OutputStream`. Could you please elaborate? Thanks